# Meaning of "cite"

Tags: meaning

> According to investigators, Brooks survived the shooting and say he was cited on two misdemeanor charges relating to the incident.

Does *cited* here mean he was asked to appear in the court? Or does it mean he was accused of the two misdemeanors? **somebody was cited on something** seems to be a very popular usage. But I'm not sure of its meaning.

Comment: AHD: 4. To issue a notice of violation to: *was cited by the police for jaywalking.*

Comment: duplicate: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/299425/whats-the-meaning-or-synonym-for-the-word-cite-here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cited) cite has several meanings, but the one you want is a specialised legal one -  **to officially name or mention someone or something in a law court, or to officially request someone to appear in a court of law**
You can be cited **on** a number of counts (here two) meaning the authorities are accusing Brooks of two offences.
Or you can be cited **for** one or more named offences, for example

> Brooks was cited **for** drunkenness and littering.